# c# regex to match only hyphen words

Tags: c#, regex

Basically if I have `aaa-aaa` it should be match. 
If it's `aaaa-bbbb---` it should match `aaaa-bbbb`
If its only `aaaa` it should NOT match.

I want to do it with regex, Any ideas ?

Currently I have

```
(?=\\S*[-])([a-zA-Z-]+)
```

Comment: what have you tried doing and where are the problems?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry about that. I currently have this as regex - "(?=\\S*[-])([a-zA-Z-]+)". Problem is that it gets aaa-bbb--- as a match(it should only get aaa-bbb) and only a word is a match(aaa is a match and it shouldn't be).

Comment: [Edit] your question to add that, formatted as code, and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Should it match all of aa-b-cc? Should it match aa--bb?

Comment: it should only match aa-b in this case.

Comment: What about aa--bb, with two hyphen?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, it should only catch a single hyphen. aa--bb should not be a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you write a regex.

- Describe what the pattern of the string you want to match is, in words.
- Find a character class, quantifier or operator that fits each feature in the pattern you described.

Let's try to describe what you want in words first.

- The string starts with a bunch of letters
- The start of the string must have one or more letters
- Then comes a hyphen
- Then there is another bunch of characters at the end
- The end of the string must have one or more letters

Now, we convert each rule into regex

- `[a-zA-Z]`
- `+`
- `-`
- `[a-zA-Z]`
- `+`

Then we join all these together to get:

```
[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: Yup, that's basically it, i guess i didn't add them in two separate character classes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bullets (2) and (5) about the start and end of the string have not been fully included. There should be a leading `^` and a trailing `$`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH No, what I meant there was the start and end of the _match_. I guess I used the wrong word :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Whitespace boundary on the front and a Word boundary at the  back.

`(?<!\S)[^-\s]+-[^-\s]+\b`